# Класс содержет в себе зночение null

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно перенести из одного скрипта функции в другой. Для этого я сделал класс, но он содержит в себе значение `null`. Проверяю с помощью `Debug.Log(hb)`.
Первый скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealsBar : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxHeals;
    public Texture HealsTexture;

    private float BarWidth;
    public float realHeals;
    private float TextureWidth;


    void Start()
    {
        BarWidth = Screen.width / 4;
        realHeals = maxHeals;
        TextureWidth = BarWidth;
    }




    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 10, BarWidth, 40), realHeals + " / " + maxHeals);

        if (HealsTexture != null && TextureWidth > 0)
        {
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(10, 30, TextureWidth, 15), HealsTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleAndCrop, true, 10.0f);
        }
    }



    public void calculatedHeals(float dmg)
    {
        if (realHeals - dmg > 0)
        {
            realHeals = realHeals - dmg;
            TextureWidth = BarWidth * (realHeals / maxHeals);
        }
        else
        {
            realHeals = 0.0f;
            TextureWidth = 0.1f;
        }
    }
```

}

Второй скрипт в который я хочу перенести функции:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Upravlenie : MonoBehaviour
{

    HealsBar hb;

    void Start () 
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Monster");
        hb = go.GetComponent<HealsBar>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(hb);
    }
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Проблемы с русским языком тебе исправить надо. На объекте go отсутствует компонент healsbar

Comment: @Xumera_hZ и как мне "положить" этот компонент на go?

Comment: Addcomponent не?